# How to obtain negative voltage from positive voltage ?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, converter

My question is simple. I have one power supply which generate 28 volt. I would like to obtain -18V and 18V. I don't want to voltage divider with resistor. I generated 18 V to use regulator. But I couldn't generate negative voltage. Is there any component which does this conversion ? if yes there is, Can I simulate it in multisim ?
Thanks for your coorperation

Comment: You have left out critical information: the current requirement. You should also explain what generates the 28 V because if that's a mains PSU it may be easy to generate an auxiliary negative from that.

Comment: I will use only to feed amplifier. I didn't find converter which obtain negative voltage from positive voltage.

Comment: You still haven't stated the current requirement.

Comment: 1.7 mA require for amplifier.

Comment: e.g. **LMC7660**

Answer (score 1):

One way is to charge up a capacitor with the positive voltage, and then disconnect the charged capacitor and connect the + lead to the ground of the circuit. You'll now have a negative voltage (relative to circuit ground) at the - lead of the charge capacity.

Of course, in practice this is typically driven by an oscillator that does the charge/disconnect/reverse cycle frequently and then uses diodes to transfer the negative charge to a holding capacitor that keep the negative voltage present continuously.

Comment: Yes that's true but complicated. I would like to use entegrated device. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

[LTC3260](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3260) from Linear Technologies is one example of the device which can translate single supply into dual supplies.

For Multisim simulation, you can just rename the supply 18V to -18V. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You are right. Just I would like to learn whether multisim has conponent(converter) has or not. Thank you so much.